# tensorflow mean_iou - how to get consistent results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation

I am stumped by the tensorflow metric mean_iou().  My attempt to use leads to inconsistent results on the same data, and I can't find a useful example anywhere.

this blog post talks about the issue...  but I can't solve my problems with the ideas here.  http://ronny.rest/blog/post_2017_09_11_tf_metrics/

End goal is to have a `validation_func(y_true, y_pred)` to pass as arg 'metric' to a Keras Model.compile() method.

**end goal**

something like...

```
def my_iou(y_true, y_pred):
  num_classes = 2
  score, update_op = tf.metrics.mean_iou(tf.argmax(y_true, axis=3), tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=3), num_classes)
  K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
  # K.get_session().run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
    final_score = tf.identity(score)
  return final_score
```

**dummy data**

- dimensions will be: (batch, height, width, num_classes)
- class 1 - foreground object; what I'm trying to segment out
- class 0 - background

what I really care about is IOU on class 1.  in this case that should be 7/9=0.778.  what I expect this to spit out though is an average of iou on each class...

- iou class 0: 0/2=0
- iou class 1: 7/9=0.778
- overall: avg(iou_0, iou_1)=0.3889

data

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

y_true = np.zeros(18, dtype='int32').reshape((1,3,3,2))
y_true[:,:,:,1] = 1
y_true[:,0,0,1] = 0
y_true[:,0,0,0] = 1

y_pred = np.zeros(18, dtype='float32').reshape((1,3,3,2))
y_pred[:,:,:,1] = 1.0
y_pred[:,-1,-1,1] = 0.1
y_pred[:,-1,-1,0] = 0.9
```

If I simulate with something like the following, I get the expected 0.3889 most of the time...  but i also get occasional 3.5 or 0.0, and I can't figure out why?

```
results = []
for i in range(20):
  with tf.Session() as sess:
    y_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_true)
    y_p = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_pred)
    results.append(my_iou(y_t, y_p).eval())
```

a recent run

```
[0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 3.5,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 3.5,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889,
 3.5,
 0.3888889,
 0.3888889]
```

any help?

**EDIT**

for now I'm using something hard coded specifically for binary classification, but I don't love it.  Not generalizable, probably too simple, and maybe outright wrong.  (also of note...  in this code, class 0 is the foreground, unlike my example setup where class 1 was the foreground)

```
def my_iou_binary(self, y_true, y_pred):
  yt0 = y_true[:,:,:,0]
  yp0 = K.cast(y_pred[:,:,:,0] > 0.5, 'float32')

  inter = tf.count_nonzero(tf.logical_and(tf.equal(yt0, 1), tf.equal(yp0, 1)))
  union = tf.count_nonzero(tf.add(yt0, yp0))
  iou = tf.where(tf.equal(union, 0), 1., tf.cast(inter/union, 'float32'))

  return iou
```

Comment: any recs on why this is getting no comments/answers?  i woulda thought this this would be a cinch for all the TensorFlow masters out there.  Is it a poorly posed question?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I think, 'weights' arg can be used to give 0 weight to background class. So for your binary case I think [0.0, 1.0] might work. I will also give it a try when I am with my desktop.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?